# Why does 24fps on blender appear slower than elsewhere?

Tags: animation, frame-rate

I've made several gif animations using blender and I always find them when played back on blender (at 24fps) they are slower than when I create the actual gif using an external application at the same rate.

Anyone know why this is?
It is extremely frustrating me

Comment: GIF files playback rates are unpredictable, I'd assume that blender's conversion codec for GIFs isn't good. Try rendering the animation as a movie file then converting. EDIT: Did you mean when you play back the GIF in blender, it plays slower than if you played the same GIF in other programs? If so that's just what blender does, I don't think there's an actual fix for it.

Comment: @JoshSilveous blender has no support for gifs (it was dropped long time ago).

Comment: Yes @JoshSilveous, the playback of the rendered animation in blender is slower than when I create a gif from the frames with another program. Perhaps the playback just plays slower than it really is.

Answer (score 1):

Blender is counting frames instead of seconds so it is probably that the frames do get a different time value.
The other thing is that it is two standards in the FPS, 24 and 23.976. That might be the problem also.

It is possible that the FPS in the preview is different from the final also.